# Как получить результатом одно из двух?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно сделать, чтобы после нажатия кнопки "проверка" с вероятностью в 50% отображался текст "Да" или "Нет"
 Как это реализовать?

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 5):

Если вам рандом нужен, то так:

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let answers = ['Да', 'Нет'];
  alert(answers[Math.floor(Math.random()*answers.length)]);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```